# No Appropriate Default Constructor Available despite default constructor made?

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, constructor, compiler-errors

Trying to make my own Map struct to store my own-created 'Strings,' and after 8 hours or so finally got it down to only a few compiler errors (six of them). I've spent the last hour and forty minutes searching the web for answers, only to find people forgot default constructors, and tried mixing things up in my own program. Since I'm not really sure where the problem is in advance, I apologize for posting all this code...I put what I thought were the most relevant files first; I think only the first 3 are necessary. The error is

```
"SubdomainPart' : No appropriate default constructor available" for lines 12 and 20 of the Map.h file.
```

**Map.h**

```
// Map.h - Map template class declaration
// Written by -----

#pragma once

template<typename KEY_TYPE, typename VALUE_TYPE>
struct Map
{
public:
    // Default / initial constructor hybrid
    Map(int initialCapacity = 10)
    {
        Size = 0;
        Capacity = initialCapacity;
        Key;
        MappedValue;

        //Allocate the C-Array elements using HEAP
        Data = new VALUE_TYPE[Capacity];
    }

    struct iterator
    {
        KEY_TYPE * current;
        KEY_TYPE * prev;
        KEY_TYPE * next;

        iterator operator ++ ()
        {
            iterator it = this;
            iterator itNext = it.next;

            it.next = itNext.next; // pushes iterator forward.
            it.prev = it.current;
            it.current = it.next;
        }
        iterator operator -- ()
        {
            iterator it = this;
            iterator itPrev = it.prev;

            it.prev = itPrev.prev; // pushes iterator backward.
            it.next = it.current;
            it.current = it.prev;
        }
    };


    Map(const Map& copyFrom)
    {
    // Necessary to prevent the delete[] Data; statement in the assignment operator from 
    // freezing because Data has some garbage address in it.
        Data = NULL;

        *this = copyFrom; //'this' points to the current instance of the object. (in this case, 'Map')
    }

    // Destructor: MUST HAVE because we allocate memory
    ~Map()
    {
        delete[] Data;
    }

    Map& operator = (const Map& copyFrom)
    {
        // 0) delete the old one!
        delete[] Data;
        // 1) copy Size and Capacity
        Size = copyFrom.Size;
        Capacity = copyFrom.Capacity;

        // 2) Allocate Memory
        Map* Data = new Map[Capacity];

        // 3) Copy the Map Elements
        for(int i = 0; i<Size; i++)
            Data[i] = copyFrom.Data[i];

        return *this;
    }

    // Index Operator
    VALUE_TYPE& operator[] (KEY_TYPE key) const
    {
        return Data[key];
    }

    // Accessor functions: read-only access to Size and Capacity
    int GetSize() const //const does not modify ANY data members of the class (size, capacity, or data)
    {
        return Size;
    }
    int GetCapacity() const
    {
        return Capacity;
    }

    void PushBack(const VALUE_TYPE& newElement) //adds value to end of Map as default
    {
        if(Size >= Capacity)
            increaseCapacity(2 * Capacity);

        Data[Size] = newElement;
        Size++; // increases size of the array so it can be used later.
    }

    // Overloaded Add function, inserts a value at specified index, calls in "Insert" to do so.
    void Add(const VALUE_TYPE& newElement, int index)
    {
        if( (index<0) || (index > Size))
        {
            throw ("Index to insert is out of range");
        }

        //Make sure there's space!
        if (Size >= Capacity)
            increaseCapacity(2*Capacity); //increase size of array if too small!

        Insert(index, newElement);  
    }

    void Remove(int index) // index = index to be removed.
    {
        // Make sure it's inside the bounds
        if( (index<0) || (index > Size))
        {
            throw ("Index to Remove is out of range.");
        }

        // it's going to remove the unneeded space by having its capacity one above the Size. 

        Map* new_Data = new Map[Size];

        //Copy data onto new pointer section.
        for(int x = 0; x<Size; x++)
            new_Data[x] = Data[x];

        delete[] Data; //deallocates old memory and uneeded capacity slots.

        for(int x = index; x < (Size - 1); x++) //removes the value at index 'index.' Now Data has a capacity of the amount of slots used and one more for a NULL value.
            new_Data[x] = new_Data[x+1];

        Data = new_Data;
        Data[Size-1] = NULL;
        Size--;
    }

    void increaseCapacity(int new_capacity)
    {
        if(new_capacity>Capacity) 
        {
            if(new_capacity> 2* Capacity)
                Capacity = new_capacity;
        else
            Capacity *= 2;

        //create Map with a new capacity!
        Map* new_Map = new Map[Capacity];

        for(int x = 0; x<Size; x++)
        {
            new_Map[x] = Data[x];
        }

        //clear out old memory
        delete[] Data;

        //set data pointer to the new Map
        Data = new_Map;
        }
    }
    KEY_TYPE * Key; // Used to identify mapped values.
    VALUE_TYPE MappedValue; // The value actually contained.
private:
    int Size; // The count of actual C-Array elements used
    int Capacity; // The count of C-array elements allocated

    // The encapsulated C-array
    VALUE_TYPE * Data; // pointer of type 'DATA_TYPE' called data (will be name of our array).

    void Insert(const int index, const VALUE_TYPE& insertValue)
    {
        if( (index<0) || (index > Size))
        {
            throw out_of_range ("Index to insert is out of range");
        }

    //Time to shuffle the array down!

    for(int x = Size; x>index; x--)
    {
        Data[x] = Data[x-1];
    }

    //Insert the new item at index 'Index!'

    Data[index] = insertValue;
    Size++;
    }

};
```

**SubdomainPart.h**

```
// SubdomainPart.h - SubdomainPart validation class declaration
// Written by -------

#pragma once

#include "String.h"
using namespace std;

class SubdomainPart
{
public:
    // Takes the address and stores into the Address data member
    SubdomainPart(const String& address);

    // Returns true when the Address is valid or false otherwise
    virtual bool IsValid();

private:
    String Address;
};
```

**SubdomainPart.cpp**

```
// SubdomainPart.cpp - Subdomain validation class implementation
// Written by ---------

#pragma once

#include "SubdomainPart.h"

// Takes the address and stores into the Address data member
SubdomainPart::SubdomainPart(const String& address)
{
    Address = address;
}

// Returns true when the Address is valid or false otherwise
bool SubdomainPart::IsValid()
{
    int currentDotIndex = 0;
    int nextDotIndex = 0;
    int found = 0; // first index of a found invalid character
    int hyphenIndex = 0; // used to check hyphen rule

    // 1. Check the size, 255 total characters
    if(Address.GetLength() < 1 || Address.GetLength() > 255)
        return false;


    // Checks for valid amount of 1-63 characters between dots

    currentDotIndex = Address.FindFirstOf('.');

    if(currentDotIndex == 0 || currentDotIndex == Address.GetLength()-1)
        return false;
    else if(currentDotIndex!=(-1))
        nextDotIndex = Address.Find('.', currentDotIndex+1);
    else
        nextDotIndex = (-1); // if no '.' is found, ensures the following loop doesn't run.

    while(nextDotIndex!=(-1))
    {
        if((nextDotIndex-currentDotIndex) == 1 || (nextDotIndex-currentDotIndex) > 63)
            return false;

        currentDotIndex = nextDotIndex;
        nextDotIndex = Address.Find('.', currentDotIndex+1);
    }   

    // 2. Check for valid characters

    found = Address.FindFirstNotOf("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-.");

    if(found!=(-1)) // if a character not listed above is found.
        return false;

    // 3. Check for dash rule

    // Making sure hyphens aren't located at the first or last index of a subdomain.

    hyphenIndex = Address.FindFirstOf('-');

    if(hyphenIndex == 0)
        return false;

    hyphenIndex = Address.FindLastOf('-');

    if(hyphenIndex == Address.GetLength()-1)
        return false;

    // Makes sure two hyphens aren't in a row.
    for(int x = 1; x<Address.GetLength(); x++)
        if(Address[x] == '-' && Address[x] == Address[x-1])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Too much code; please reduce your example to a minimal code.

Comment: Now that I know what the problem was, I'll delete the other stuff. The last few questions I've had I've been chastised for trying to keep the amount code short and readable, so I'm still working on finding a middle ground.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to remove as much code as possible whilst still retaining the same error message. You can usually reproduce errors in less than 15 lines of code. The work of doing this usually gives you insight, and you might not even have to post your question. Get an account with one of those fancy new fangled on-line c++ compilers and start chopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a default constructor in this class:

```
class SubdomainPart
{
public:
    // Takes the address and stores into the Address data member
    SubdomainPart(const String& address);

    // Returns true when the Address is valid or false otherwise
    virtual bool IsValid();

private:
    String Address;
};
```

Keep in mind that this map constructor is default-constructing every member rather than initializing them:

```
Map(int initialCapacity = 10)
{
    Size = 0;
    Capacity = initialCapacity;
    Key;
    MappedValue;

    //Allocate the C-Array elements using HEAP
    Data = new VALUE_TYPE[Capacity];
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Why did it show 'map.h' as the source of the error then?

Comment: @Reciever80 Because that's where the default constructor is used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a **default** constructor for `SubdomainPart` you have only provided a copy constructor. A default constructor takes no argument.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Since the error list pointed to the 'map.h' file, I assumed it was having issues with the constructor in there.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining that `SubdomainPart` doesn't have a default constructor, and indeed it doesn't. It's required because your `Map` contains an object of type `VALUE_TYPE`:

```
VALUE_TYPE MappedValue;
```

Also, your `Map` constructor contains very weird code. I assume you actually wanted to use an initialiser list:

```
Map(int initialCapacity = 10)
  : Key()
  , MappedValue()
  , Size(0)
  , Capacity(initialCapacity)
  , Data(new VALUE_TYPE[Capacity])
{}
```

Comment: It's 4:30 AM right now :) I'm trying to get as much code written as I can so it's less to do later. What's the difference between what you posted and what I posted? The layout/format that I used was provided by our professor, for discussion sake.

Comment: What you posted default-initialised all the members, and then assigned into `Size`, `Capacity` and `Data`. The statements `Key;` and `MappedValue;` didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `Data = new VALUE_TYPE[Capacity];` part.
The compiler generates code to allocate the array and instantiate each element by calling the parameterless constructor for VALUE_TYPE. As SubdomainPart doesn't have one (since you have defined a custom one), the compiler throws an error.

The reason that compiler reports error in map.h is that it is exactly the place where the constructor is called from. It is not used in SubdomainPart code, it is just defined there.

Comment: Thanks! I asked the others the same thing, so if they've replied already don't feel like you have to as well, but why did it show 'map.h' as the source of the error then?

Comment: When I started typing (from my mobile phone on a bus which takes significantly more time) there was no answer yet. I have also updated the answer with explanation for error location